# Chisq Test R : Multiple group in data frame

Tags: r

I'm new on R and trying to run some statistical test.

My data looks like that :

```
Name    Freqeunce   Target  Total
Steve   1   A   11
Marcel  1   A   11
Marie   1   A   11
John    2   A   11
Max     2   A   11
Alice   4   A   11
Mariane 1   B   1
Rose    1   C   3
Carla   1   C   3
Happy   1   C   3
```

I want to realise a Chi2 of homogeneity for each target type ( A, B and C).

I want to know if there is possibility with R to run a loop that will write the p.value of each name in a column or did i have to extract the information before and then realize the Chi2 ? 
The objectif is to identify which the different name are less represented in the group according to the frequences. And there is more than 2000 groups, thats why i want a loop.

Thank you for your answer

Baptiste

Comment: If you can show an example of how you would do the chi^2 test for one group that would make it easier to find a solution for all of the groups. Also an example of your desired output would help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will answer your question. I don't know if this is the type of chi^2 test you want but you can always change the function. I use `group_by` and `mutate` from the `dplyr` package and write a function to perform the chi^2 test and extract the pvalue.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- read.table("test2.txt", header = T)

c2_all <- function(x,y){
  mat <- matrix(c(x,y),nrow = 2)  
  c2 <- chisq.test(mat)
  return(c2$p.value)
}

result <- df2 %>% group_by(Target) %>% mutate(pvalue = c2_all(Name,Freqeunce))

result
# A tibble: 11 x 5
# Groups:   Target [3]
   Name    Freqeunce Target Total pvalue
   <fct>       <int> <fct>  <int>  <dbl>
 1 Steve           1 A         11  0.285
 2 Marcel          1 A         11  0.285
 3 Marie           1 A         11  0.285
 4 John            2 A         11  0.285
 5 Max             2 A         11  0.285
 6 Alice           4 A         11  0.285
 7 Sarah           2 B          3  1.00 
 8 Mariane         1 B          3  1.00 
 9 Rose            1 C          5  0.223
10 Carla           3 C          5  0.223
11 Happy           1 C          5  0.223
```